# Find the newest item in a 2 columns predecessor-successor list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have two columns in Excel with phase-out and phase-in items:

| Old item | New item |
| --- | --- |
| AAAAAAAAA | BBBBBBBBB |
| GGGGGGGGG | DDDDDDDDDD |
| BBBBBBBBB | KKKKKKKKKK |
| KKKKKKKKK | CCCCCCCCCC |

I'm trying to write a formula that when I enter an item code in another cell, it returns the most recent one.

Example:
If I insert `AAAAAAAAA` it should return `CCCCCCCCC`, or If I write `GGGGGGGGG` it should return: `DDDDDDDDD`.

I tried using the `MATCH` function and `VLOOKUP` but it turned up nothing.

Comment: I'd expect `AAAAAAAAA` to return `BBBBBBBBB`. Is that a typo?

Comment: No, because `AAAAAAAAA` has been replaced by `BBBBBBBBB`, but `BBBBBBBBB` has been replaced by `KKKKKKKKK`, and `KKKKKKKKK` has been replaced by `CCCCCCCCCC`.  So the newest one is `CCCCCCCCCC`

Comment: Then you need to make some recursive lambda function for example.

Comment: Or you can keep the old ones in the left column but for each put the latest item code. Which means that AAAAAAAAA will be CCCCCCCCCC and BBBBBBBBB will also be CCCCCCCCCC The vlookup(), xlookup() and index() with match() will all work with a single layer instead of needing something recursive. Just means keeping a table up to date...

Comment: @SolarMike That's exactly my problem: I need the latest item code, but there are thousands of rows, I can't update the table manually. I need a way to find the latest item automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you haven't got any answer just yet, so let me clarify my comment. As I see it, you need some form of recursion; a mechanic perfectly suited for `LAMBDA()` which can call itself. MS designed a usefull helper function called `REDUCE()`:

[image]

The formula in `E2`:

```
=LET(X,$A$2:$A$5,Y,$B$2:$B$5,REDUCE(D2,X,LAMBDA(a,b,FILTER(Y,X=a,a))))
```

---

Or, if you want to calculate the same for a whole range of items to look for:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=BYROW(D2:D3,LAMBDA(Z,LET(X,A2:A5,Y,B2:B5,REDUCE(Z,X,LAMBDA(a,b,FILTER(Y,X=a,a))))))
```

---

**Important Note**:

`REDUCE()` will run untill the very end of the matrix given in the 2nd parameter. For a very extensive array this can take much more processing time then necessarily needed. Imagine running 10k lines when there is only 1 new item found in the 2nd line of data. Therefor, you could also write your own recursive function. This can be done in two ways:

- A named function in the manager to call in a cell;
- Through the use of `LET()`.

This 2nd option has my personal preverence, for example in `E2`:

```
=LET(NEWEST,LAMBDA(ME,TXT,IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A$5,TXT),ME(ME,XLOOKUP(TXT,A$2:A$5,B$2:B$5,,0)),TXT)),NEWEST(NEWEST,D2))
```

Though much more verbose, this could take much less resources depending on your data as it would stop the recursive call upon when no more new value could be found.

Comment: Perfectly worked in a range of 10K, just tested!

Comment: Sir, much thanks for all these, I am evaluating the final solution, to learn more, however I found that the combination of `LET()` `REDUCE()` & `LAMBDA()` is deadly combination. Super fast like **5G**!